# Driving from New York to Toronto, Canada - Transit visa - Indian citizen

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, canada, transit-visas

I am an Indian citizen studying in America with an F1-visa, and I have a flight that departs from Toronto. I want to drive to the Toronto airport in Canada from New York (NYC), and I will not be visiting anyone. The Canadian visa webpage mentioned that I will require a transit visa because I will be in the country for less than 48 hours.

1. In addition to using the transit visa at the airport, I wanted to know if the transit visa is valid for an Indian citizen driving into the country from America?
2. How long does it usually take to obtain a transit visa?

**EDIT**

3. I plan to fly back into Canada, and drive back into America through Canada. Will I need a transit visa on my way back from Canada? I think I will need one in Canada since I should be okay with my F1-visa while encountering the American immigration officials at the American-Canadian border.

Thanks!

Comment: I presume your flight is to a destination outside Canada.  Why would you need a transit visa at the airport?  You will only need it at the border when you enter by car.  I do not know how long the application will require, but if you are returning to the US in F1 status, it seems like it ought to be fairly routine.

Comment: @phoog Canada, like the US, does not have sterile transit areas at its airports. So he would need a transit visa even if flying from the US via Canada.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, sure, but he's planning to drive into Canada, not fly there.

Comment: @phoog Yes, I plan on going to Cuba for my spring break. Since there are no flights directly going to Havana from any city in America, I am planning on flying through Cuba. I live in Pennsylvania, and I will most probably be in NYC for a few days before I rent a car and drive up north to Toronto.

Comment: You can easily fly to Miami and then connect to a direct flight to Havana. The problem is that currently you can't book them together; they must be booked separately. The agency or airline you book your MIA-HAV tickets through will arrange your tourist card.

Comment: Travelocity is quoting almost $500 for JFK-YYZ car rental for two days at the end of March/early April.

Answer (score 3):

Transit visas are for *entering the country on the way to some other country*. I've never heard of one that was specific as to mode of travel. You could drive, bicycle, or even ride a horse if you were granted enough time to do so. I'd be more worried about what you will do with the car you're driving.

Currently the [processing time](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/times/temp/visitors.asp) for Canada visa applications made in the US is listed as 12 days. Canada now updates this information weekly. (At the original time of this post, the processing time was listed as 52 days and [listed by visa office](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=1185&top=3).)

You should apply for your visa as soon as possible, or schedule a flight which does not start in or transit Canada.

Comment: Perhaps OP is planning to park in long-term parking and retrieve the car on the way home.

Comment: @phoog It's uncommon for people in NYC to own cars, so I suspect it's a rental. Personally I would not leave a rental in long-term parking for _days_, and renting a car in one country and returning it in another is difficult at best. And since it's easy to find flights from NYC to India, I suspect something else is going on here that we don't know about and possibly that an immigration officer might not like if he knew about it.

Comment: There are 1.8 million "standard" vehicle registrations in New York city alone, never mind that the OP could also live in the suburbs.  It's very common not to own a car in New York City, but it's also not unusual to own one.  On the other hand, it's also odd to drive 12 hours to catch a plane.  I didn't register that this was NY *City* until your last comment.

Comment: @phoog Oh, certainly it's _possible_, but it doesn't strike me as _likely_ that a _foreign student_ in NYC would bother to buy a car. Public transit is plenty good enough, and parking can cost more than the car payment!

Comment: It really depends on where he lives and perhaps goes to school.  There are parts of the outer boroughs where life without a car is very inconvenient, and where parking can be done for free on the street or in the house's driveway.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I got to school in Pennsylvania, and my final destination is Havana, Cuba. I am planning on going there for spring break. I need a transit visa because there are no direct flights from any city in America to Havana. I plan to rent a car (probably in NYC, enterprise mostly) and drop it off at the Toronto airport.

Comment: @Eagle one-way car rentals typically cost hundreds of dollars.

Comment: I'm working on the Canadian rules, but in the UK a transit visa is valid only if you arrive and leave by air.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The visa to Cuba can be purchased at the airport (at the counter of the airline that you are flying through). With regard to the immigration officer, that is exactly what I plan to tell him/her. I don't have the Cuban tourist card yet, and I plan to buy one at the ticket counter.

Comment: @Eagle There are plenty of MIA-HAV flights available, but you can't usually book them with a connecting flight. And a rental from the US dropped off in Canada will be _very expensive_...

Comment: I have seen cars with Ontario plates in a USA rental car company lot, but I still doubt very much if this idea is feasible by car. However, there is one train per day!

Comment: @MichaelHampton I see. Well, I am unable to look for flights from Miami to Havana because of the restriction the American government has placed on searching for flights to Cuba within the United States. I am planning on driving to Canada because it seems to cost $250 to rent a car through Enterprise.

Comment: @MichaelHampton On my way back to America, would I need an additional transit visa for the return journey from Toronto to NYC/Pennsylvania? I think I may need to, but I just wanted to confirm. Please see an edit to my original question.

Comment: @Eagle Very strange, I'm in the US - and American - and have no trouble booking MIA-HAV. Type MIA-HAV into Google and you're off. As for a Canada transit visa, you should apply for both entries when you apply for the transit visa, if you decide to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The transit visa allows you to transit through the country; it does not have any other restrictions. Some countries (for example, Saudi Arabia) have restrictions on their visas that dictate the method of entry to the country - but Canada does not have such conditions.

Therefore, the visa to transit is as valid for you to enter Canada as it is for you to transit through the airport - *as long as the intention of your visit is to transit*.

Keep in mind that the decision to let you enter is at the discretion of the CBSA officers at the border. You'll have to convince them of the nature and purpose of your trip. I only mention this because it is highly unusual for someone to cross the land border with a transit visa - but there is nothing wrong (legally) with doing so; but as it is unusual it may warrant further checks/inspections/questions/delays at the border; so be prepared for that.

Assuming you are able to get the visa in time; its a nice 10+ hour drive (given traffic and congestion at the border). Its approximately 500 miles.